# User leaving app JavaScript callback on Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need a method to execute when the user leaves the app, the app is suspended and is supposed to save resources etc.

What is this on Windows 10 (UWP) if I'm writing the app in JavaScript?

Basically I need Android's `onPause`.

Comment: [oncheckpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229839.aspx) or just onblur, depending on your needs.

Comment: See my answer I found it in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this:

```
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("suspending", () => {
    // handle suspend
});
```